# Deriving Quadratic Function Using Table of Values

Tags: quadratics

How do you derive a quadratic function given its table of values when there is no zero x value given?

For example,
x|1|2|3
y|-6|-3|4

I tried two methods in solving this but I can only get a. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know Mathjax?

Comment: Can you explain us a little bit more precise what is the task. Which methods have you tried?

Comment: Take $y=ax^2+bx+c$. Then substitute the 3 pairs to it. You will have 3 equations of 3 unknowns. Then you can have a,b,c

Answer (score 1):

You know that $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ for suitable $a,b,c$. We are also given
$$\begin{align}a+\hphantom{1}b+c&=f(1)=-6\\
4a+2b+c&=f(2)=-3\\
9a+3b+c&=f(3)=\hphantom{-}4\end{align} $$
That's three equations in three unknowns ...

Comment: I actually used that method but I didn't know how to go further. I tried elimination, and it kinda failed. I'm dumb, sorry.